# Unable to deserialize the Web Api Core Response in a wcf service

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

'WcfEntAdmin' is the WcfService which internally calls the WebApi Core service to fetch some data. I use the HttpClient to call the WebApi Core service. The call return successfully with 200 status code but when I try to deserialize the response, the application goes to break state. I'm unsure what could be going wrong.

```
public class ApiHelper
{
private readonly JWTHandler _jwtHandler;
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
private readonly HttpClient _secureHttpClient;

public ApiHelper()
{
_httpClient = new HttpClient(ConfigureHandler());
_jwtHandler = new JWTHandler("myusername", "test", memoryCache, new AuthorizationClient(_configuration, _httpClient));
_jwtHandler.InnerHandler = ConfigureHandler();
_secureHttpClient = new HttpClient(_jwtHandler);
}

public bool IsAutoPolicy()
{
// the code here makes a call to the Web Api Core using the _securityHttpClient and determines if it's a Auto Policy or not 
}

public async Task<ApiVehiclesInfo> GetVehicleList(string policyNumber, DateTime effectiveDate)
{
    ApiVehiclesInfo vehiclesInfo = new ApiVehiclesInfo();
    if (IsPATEnabled())
    {
      var secureApiClient = new BaseApiClient(_configuration, _secureHttpClient);
      var response = await secureApiClient.GetAsync("PolicyApi",$"legacy_adapter/vehicles/{policyNumber}/{effectiveDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd")}");
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
          try
          {
            vehiclesInfo = await response.Deserialize<ApiVehiclesInfo>();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
          }
     }
  }
return vehiclesInfo;
}
```

The calling code first makes a call to the `IsAutoPolicy()` and then calls the `GetVehiclesList("1234567",DateTime.Now)`.
[image: Break Mode]

EDIT: I have Deserialize as the Extension method of the HttpResponseMessage as

```
public static async Task<TResult> Deserialize<TResult>(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    try
    {
       using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
       using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
       using (JsonReader textReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
       {
           JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer
           {
               NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
               MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
           };
        return serializer.Deserialize<TResult>(textReader);
        }
   }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Data.Add("StatusCode", response.StatusCode);
        ex.Data.Add("ReasonPhrase", response.ReasonPhrase);
        throw new SerializationException("Failed to deserialize", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you return the response from the api, you cannot directly
> deserialize the response.

You need to obtain the returned json through the following code, and then deserialize:

```
 string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 vehiclesInfo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiVehiclesInfo>(responseString);
```

Comment: I edited the question to include the code for the ```Deserialize(this HttpResponseMessage response)``` extension method. Even then I tried the steps you provided. But still I get the break state